# Calling a model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I made a command in which I have to pass my model name to process some data. How can I call it from the controller as I can't mention it as `App\Models\{ModelName}` because in controller the model's name is passed as a string.

Basically my doubt is, if in a function of a controller my model's name is passed as a string, how can I fetch it?

Comment: You mean you want to get the model's instance in a method to work with it??

Comment: @Saud yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. And no laravel won't consider it as a string.

```
$namespace = 'App\\Models\\';
$model = $namespace.'Foo';

$result = $model::where('status', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the model goes in the text, you can use it like this

```php
$class = 'App\Models\User';

return $class::find(1);
```